# Parent div is blocking cursor focus from child divs in IE7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

Here's the idea: I have a div element, #content_wrapper, which encompasses three floated divs, #left_column, #nav, and #content. Here's the styles on the #content_wrapper:

```
#content_wrapper {
    float:left; 
    background: url("images/bg-tan.jpg") repeat-y left center; 
    position:relative;
}
```

However, in Internet Explorer 7 the #content_wrapper seems to steal the cursor from the child elements. Whenever I hover over the #content_wrapper, the cursor always switches to a beam and I'm unable to click on any of the links or text inside the div. Thoughts?

Update: I've tried the following fixes, none of which have worked.

- Applying fixed width to all elements, including parent and top level children
- Apply position: relative to all elements and then z-index
- Using !important on all the above properties in case
- Adding the "zoom" property to parent and child divs
- Adding the "overflow" property to the parent div

Comment: How about linking us to the real page? Or obviously mimic it if you can't publish it online...

Comment: Try removing `repeat-y left center`

Comment: Oh, my apologies -- forgot to link it!
@sAc: those are just background styles... they wouldn't affect the issue [but I tried it anyway, and no luck].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#content_wrapper { position: relative; z-index: -1; width: 1010px; }
```

**EDIT: You are setting the z-index of #content_wrapper to -1. This is why it's happening.** Get rid of it or set it to a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#content_wrapper {
    zoom: 1
}
```

Comment: @Will: Try adding `overflow:auto;` to your wrapper.

Comment: Still no luck with that either. Plus, I can't do that as there are absolutely positioned elements that go outside of the wrapper.

Comment: also you can try to add zoom: 1; to wrapers childs - #left_column, #nav, and #content. It could help

Comment: #content_wrapper > * { zoom: 1; }
Still no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure but seems like ie7 does not know #el > * selector, try to assign the style dirrectly